# IO Exception while loading images from url in android

Tags: android, image, url

I am trying to load images from url and I can display some of them in an Imageview.My problem is that I am getting

09-04 10:18:25.739: W/System.err(913): java.io.IOException: Expected a hex chunk size, but was

while decoding some images and can't display the same.

This is my code

public class downloadTask extends AsyncTask
    {

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        URL link = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            try {
                link = new URL(url_Link[i]);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                //bm[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) link.getContent());
                bm[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(link.openConnection().getInputStream());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("entered"+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            publishProgress(i);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        iv[values[0]].setImageBitmap(bm[values[0]]);
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

}
```

What is wrong in this?

Anyone help please..Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](http://www.mediafire.com/?xlt6s61v14d38x7) and [this](http://www.mediafire.com/?gv1bo5m8ewjhdyf) example will help you more than i can explain:) [code is the best documentation :P]